# Can we use articles with adjectives?

Tags: grammar, articles

https://m.9gag.com/gag/aGeAxDw
In this video
the girl says *I think I can smell the spiritual*

As far as I know articles can not be used with adjectives . No?

Answer (score 10):

An adjective can often be used with a determiner (in this case the definite article) to become a noun that refers to all things that can be described by the adjective.

For example:

> **The rich** get richer and **the poor** get poorer.

or:

> When the going gets tough, **the tough** get going.

or even:

> “... Give me **your tired**, **your poor**,
>
> Your huddled masses yearning to breathe free,
>
> The wretched refuse of your teeming shore.
>
> Send these, **the homeless**, tempest-tossed to me,
>
> I lift my lamp beside the golden door!”

A more sensible use of "the spiritual" might be:

> "When we go in search of the spiritual, we leave the physical behind.

Here "the spiritual" refers to "any or all spiritual things".

In the video, the joke is that "the spiritual" is taken to mean sweaty body odour. I shows that she doesn't understand or believe yoga's spiritual value and sees it only as a sweaty exercise.

Comment: But the spiritual doesn't make no sense

Comment: And in the third one it should've been give me your tiredness ,your poverty

Comment: "your tired" people, "your poor" people

Comment: The joke in the video is entirely different from this.

Comment: This is precisely it.  "The *adjective*" = "those things which are *adjective*".

Answer (score 3):

Uggh, what an annoying video. What is meant to be cute and funny is just weird.

What the girl says is a pretty clever joke. I would say this is pretty advanced English. She says:

> The teacher says yoga is spiritual.
>
> I think I can smell the spiritual.

Normally, you can't add "the" to "spiritual," but since this is a joke and informal, it's OK here. The girl is implying more than what she says. What she is implying is the following:

> The teacher says yoga is spiritual, but it's actually just sweat.
>
> I think I can smell the sweat.

This is a clever joke that adults sometimes make. It's facilitated by adding "the" to "spiritual," which is the hint that "spiritual" actually means something else -- in this case, it means either "sweat" or "body odor" or something similar. How do we know this? We are supposed to deduce that it's sweat because it's something you can smell while doing a physical activity. Once you solve this little riddle in your head, you can now understand the true meaning of the joke.

Children aren't really capable of being this sophisticated and sarcastic, so it's pretty clear that her parents told her to say this. She can barely pronounce the words!

Comment: You mean she wants to say 'i can smell what's spiritual'?

Comment: What she wants to say is simply, "Yoga is sweaty and i can smell it"

Comment: "I think I can smell the spiritual" is a clever way of saying "Yoga is sweaty and I can smell it"

Comment: Okay. There's a band called the holy  . What does that mean? Holy too is an adjective right? 

Comment: A band name doesn't have to follow any grammatical rules, so I wouldn't look at band names as examples. But sometimes you can leave off the noun and just use the adjective if it's obvious what the noun is. In this case, "the holy" refers to people, so it's KIND OF acceptable to leave off the noun and just use "the holy."

Comment: But the holy leaves the listener in doubt. The holy what? It should be followed by a noun like. The holy water or the holy spirit or something

Comment: In this case, "the holy" would normally refer to people. In general, if an adjective without a noun can refer to people, that is often the intention of the author. In the case of a band, they might actually want vagueness or doubt

Comment: Or maybe the music they make?

Comment: Sure, many bands want to seem dark and doubtful and mysterious, just like their name. :-)

Comment: It is not only informal. This style can be used in quite formal English. It sounds quite literary, as the quotations in other answers show.

Comment: @user236989 A bit of advice: you seem to be using the word "should" a lot, as though the native speakers using these constructions are wrong and you know better. As a second language learner, you should start from the assumption that native speakers know what they're doing, and seek to make sense of it (of course, native speakers can use their own language incorrectly, but you shouldn't start from the assumption that they are doing so). In the case of this band name, I think it would be safe to interpret "holy" as referring to the band members themselves.

Comment: @JLRishe who is user236969. I would assume it's me, but I don't use the word "should" at all in my answer or comments. Whereas you use it twice. :-)

Comment: @Ringo I was trying to direct my comment at user62691, the OP of this question, regarding their comments on your answer and that of smatterer. Not sure where I came up with 236969, and the person at whom I had intended to direct my comment has since deleted their account.

Comment: I think OP was just trying to communicate his misunderstanding -- not trying to correct native speakers. but it's all moot, i guess. i wonder what would cause him to delete the account

Answer (score 3):

This is a common construction in English.  The adjective is nominalized, that is to say, it functions as an abstract noun that embodies the characteristic expressed by the adjective.

> People visit this ancient well to experience the holy.

Here, **the holy** could be paraphrased **holyness itself** (var. sp **holiness**).

> Hardy's works often deal with the tragic.

It can also be used to refer to a *class* of individuals possessing the trait expressed by the adjective:

> Victory goes to the swift.

Answer (score 0):

This is called a substantive adjective meaning that it has enough substance to act like a noun. The noun is understood but not stated.